# Meta Data refresh while looping through tables in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, script-task

The situation:  I have a list of queries written so that each select data from their respective table. I want to create this list of queries as an SSIS object variable and iterate through each one, using the query as a OLE DB source in a DFT.

Is there any way to do this so that the DFT source component does not have an issue with the meta data being incorrect, after we switch to a query using a different table than the first?

The destination will also be changing as well. I know that you can delay the validation but i don't believe that helps with the switching meta data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if the meta data is not the same for all queries, then you cannot use them in a single data flow task.   The meta data for a DFT is set at design time, and cannot change or "refresh" during a run.  You're correct that delaying validation will not help with this.

You might want to look into BiML, which dynamically creates packages based on meta data.